# Opening an ActiveStorage class results in other methods disappearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to add an instance method to `ActiveStorage::Attachment`. My understanding is that the correct way to achieve that is to open the class in an initializer file, so I created a file with this:

```
class ActiveStorage::Attachment
  def serialize
    {} # this is different in my case, but it's not relevant
  end
end
```

Now, the error `NoMethodError (undefined method '_reflect_on_association' for ActiveStorage::Attachment:Class):` is raised whenever I call `a.present?`, where `a` is an instance of `ActiveStorage::Attached::One`.

Any ideas?

EDIT: after following the suggestion in the comments, I changed the class declaration to `class ActiveStorage::Attachment < ActiveStorage::Record` (added parent class). Now the error is
`ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the inverse association for file_attachment (:record in ActiveStorage::Attachment)`

Comment: No idea why this would be happening but nowadays when "altering" rails classes, most people will write a module and then add it to the class via `extend` or `include` depending on the desired scope.

Comment: Is there any advantage to doing that vs just adding a single method the way I did in my example?

Comment: Well for one you don't have to worry about the Inheritance ambiguity caused by what you posted (surprised this didn't raise any errors)  e.g. `class ActiveStorage::Attachment` should be  `class ActiveStorage::Attachment < ActiveStorage::Record`

Comment: That makes sense, I'll consider it in the future. I updated my question with your suggestion as the error changed. I also tried adding it as a module but it raised the same error.